# Authorization in tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm followed a tutorial for using tweepy to post something to twitter, everything works but i gave the code to a friend so he could post something using my twitter app(with my credentials consumer key and secret). mine works because i already have my acces token, but how can he get the his access token?

i have tried using the Oauth tutorial, but every example ask for the PIN, but i can't manage to get that PIN.

here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy, time, sys

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

#enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application:
CONSUMER_KEY = 'MY TOKEN'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer key
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'MY TOKEN'#keep the quotes, replace this with your consumer secret key
ACCESS_KEY = '?????????????????????????'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token
ACCESS_SECRET = '?????????????????????????'#keep the quotes, replace this with your access token secret
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()


for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(180)#Tweet every 3 minutes
```

Comment: To get his own AS/AK https://apps.twitter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, just leave callback blank and it will give you a PIN.

Also with another code and the PIN i can store the tokens and use it in my app.

SOLVED.